# Array sorting and removing duplicates

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array and remove duplicates.This is  the function i am using in c
this code is errorfree but gives me wrong output as there are 0's in the  output array. whereas there were no zeros originally

```
sort(int tab[], int k)
{
    int temp,i,j,m; 
    for(i=0; i<k; i++){

        for(j =i+1; j<k; j++)
        {
            if(tab[i] > tab[j])
            {
                int  temp = tab[i];
                tab[i]=tab[j];
                tab[j]=temp;
            }
            else if (tab[i] == tab[j]){ 

                for (m =j; m<k; m++){
                    tab[m] = tab[m+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

what is the logical error in this code?I am getting 0's in my output

Comment: Start by formatting / properly indenting this creature of evil

Comment: The code you posted produces no output. Please provide a clear example of how your output is produced, what output you expect, and what output you actually see.

Comment: Questions of this sort are off-topic on Stackoverflow. You are expected to do you own debugging, not just include a code dump and a brief sentence asking others to find your error.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct... but you forgot to do a `k--;`
since you are removing a duplicate each time the size will decrease by `1`..

```
sort(int tab[], int k)
{ 
    int temp,i,j,m;

    for( i=0;i<k;i++)
        for( j =i+1;j<k;j++)
        {
            if(tab[i]>tab[j])
            {
                int temp = tab[i];
                tab[i]=tab[j];
                tab[j]=temp;
            }
            else if (tab[i]==tab[j])
            {
                for ( m =j ; m<k;m++)
                    tab[m]=tab[m+1];

                k--;
            } //end of else if
        }// end of for
}
```